# MSSQL - Service fails to start after disk move (Event 7024)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 on my development PC had its data in `C:\DATA\MSSQL\...`. I renamed this folder then added a new SSD physical disk and mounted it as `C:\DATA` and moved the files right back, with all services stopped.

Move went fine, other apps seem oblivious to the changes, yet MSSQL won't start. Initially in the Windows Event Log (Application) the MSSQL service itself reported Access Denied errors on the master DB files.

I sorted out the ACLs and now the service begins to start and, in fact, the Application log reports no errors but the service fails to start.

The System Log reports this:

> The SQL Server (SQL2014) service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
>   WARNING: You have until SQL Server (SQL2014) to logoff. If you have not logged off at this time, your session will be disconnected, and any open files or devices you have open may lose data.

The message is nonsensical, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had ticked to enable disk compression when making the new volume on the SSD. I wrongly assumed it meant enable it as an option, as opposed to enable it and compress the whole disk.

No matter, I uncompressed the MSSQL subfolder where all the data resides and it started no problem.